# How to catch commit action on svn server with writing hooks through pysvn?

Tags: svn

I want to catch any commit action on svn server.But I cant write hooks on server.

can I do it through pysvn? And I found pysvn provide a transaction object. But I dont know

how to use it. Can u help?

Answer (score 0):

SVN has no remote notification API by itself. The only thing you can do, is to poll the server log.

You can do this with pysvn, as with any other svn client to.